# Azimuthal angle in bloch sphere

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

I was wondering if there is any direct physical meaning behind the Bloch sphere parametrization in the sense that if I choose the angle $\phi =0$, then what does this mean for my spin state?

Does anybody know about this? 
[I am referring to this wikipedia convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\phi=0$, the state lies in the $x$-$z$-plane, i.e., it is of the form $\alpha\lvert0\rangle+\beta\lvert1\rangle$ with $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R$.